# Storing certificates in domain-wise cert files not in acme.json

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, traefik

I'm using traefik as my reverse proxy and one of my docker container services (mqtt) needs it's LE generated certificate (the one stored in acme.json)  for authentication.

The docs for Key-value store config (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kv-config/) are more confusing than helping me in this situation.
Does somebody have some advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

There's stuff like the [Traefik Certificate Extractor](https://github.com/DanielHuisman/traefik-certificate-extractor), which works fine in a small setup. It reads the acme.json and exports `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` which you can then use in other containers.